# Spark List in Actionscript: Passing Layout & itemRenderer in construtctor

Tags: list, actionscript, parameters

I am trying to create a generic List, where I can pass the layout & item renderer as parameters.

Since it is not possible to pass parameters to a MXML component's Constructor, I figured I should create my List in Actionscript.

I figured it would go something like this:

```
public class GenericList extends List {
   public function GenericList(iR:ItemRenderer, ac:ArrayCollection, layout:LayoutBase) {
     super();
     this.dataProvider = ac;
     this.layout =  ...     // don't even have access to this.layout
     this.itemRenderer = iR // Cannot pass itemRender 
}
```

I would prefer to have the List in MXML (because It will be easier using states later), but If I am forced to use pure Actionscript so I can instantiate it and pass in parameters, any help would go a long way.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the itemRenderer property of a list must implement IClassFactory.  So your assignment would look like this:

```
public function GenericList(cf:ClassFactory, ac:ArrayCollection, layout:LayoutBase) {
```

And the instantiation would be:

```
var myList:GenericList = new GenericList( new ClassFactory( com.company.renderers.MyItemRenderer, ....);
```

---

Regarding the layout:
List essentially wraps DataGroup, so it is the datagroup's layout that you need to access.  However, dataGroup will not necessarily be instantiated yet.  So you might have to create a private property that you then utilize in commitProperties.

```
private var _myLayout:LayoutBase; (populate in constructor via getter/setter)
protected var layoutInvalidated:Boolean;

public function set myLayout( layout:LayoutBase):void {
    _myLayout = layout;
    layoutInvalidated = true;
}

override protected function commitProperties():void {
    super.commitProperties();
    if( layoutInvalidated && dataGroup && dataGroup.layout ) {
        layoutInvalidated = false;
        dataGroup.layout = _myLayout;
    }
}
```